# Using variable to add and remove a form input field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a hidden input field to a form when a span with class="checkbox" is clicked, and remove that same field when span with checkmark is clicked.

I am able to add the input, but **I cannot remove it**.

My HTML:

```
<span title="Here's My Title" class="wishlistcheck checkbox">1</span>

<form id="wishlistform"></form>
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var appNum = 0;

    $("span.wishlistcheck").click(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var appName = el.attr("title");

        var isChecked = el.hasClass('checkmark');
        if(!isChecked) {
            el.removeClass('checkbox');
            el.addClass('checkmark');

            appNum++

            $("#wishlistform").append("<input id=\"" + appName + "\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"product_" + appNum + "\" value=\"" + appName + "\">");


        } else {
            el.removeClass('checkmark');
            el.addClass('checkbox');

            appNum--

            $("input#" + appName).remove();




        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you are aware that `appNum++` and `appNum--` are statements, and need a semicolon after them right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have to put the `appNum--` after the .remove() method calling. Try it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var appNum = 0;
    $("span.wishlistcheck").click(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var appName = el.attr("title");
        var isChecked = el.hasClass('checkmark');
        if(!isChecked) {
            el.removeClass('checkbox');
            el.addClass('checkmark');
            appNum++
            $("#wishlistform").append("<input class=\"" + appName + "\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"product_" + appNum + "\" value=\"" + appName + "\">");
        } else {
            el.removeClass('checkmark');
            el.addClass('checkbox');
            appNum--
            $("input[class=" + appName + "]").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So try using the same code, but selecting it by it's class (as rposky said), an not by it's id

Comment: Perfect! It works like this too... $("input[id=" + appName + "]").remove();

Answer (score 2):

You probably have multiple DOM elements by that id tag, and so it may be removing an element matching that id but not the right one.

Try giving it a class name instead and getting more specific in your jQuery parameters by adding parent elements, i.e.

```
 $('#wishlistform input#' + appName).remove();
```

Comment: You say to give it a class name instead, and yet you still use `#` instead of `.` in the selector ?

Comment: I tried that too (using the parent form id, even though it is the only element on the page with that id). It didn't work.

Comment: True, I didn't know what class name he would assign though :p